Why multiple audio html elements fails inside v-for?
I'm trying to play multiple songs on the same page inside a Vue3 Component.
I have 5 songs and just one plays. The other 4 just displays and that's all.
                <li v-for="song in songs" :key="song.id">
                    <div class="bg-green-500 text-white p-4">
                        <div class="bg-blue-500 text-white p-4 w-1/6"> 
                            <audio controls :src="song.value"></audio>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>


I don't think that you can play 5 songs at the same time in a Web environment from the same page. Have you checked the MDN docs related to this? I assume that there is no async operation here.

Are you starting the audio via user interaction or programmatically?  what debugging have you done?  Are all song.value values correct?  Using just a single <audio> element can you play each song individually?  What if you load the 1 working song on all 5 audio elements, does that work?  Any console errors or warnings?  You can play multiple audio elements simultaneously, but whatever the issue is is unique to your setup and implementation, which we know very little about.
